# Why does material-ui styling flash when navigating between pages in Next.js?

Tags: material-ui, next.js

https://yesnomaybe.menu/questions/1

When clicking a button on the above page, the buttons on the next page flash in a different styling before matching the previous page's buttons. Code:

https://github.com/lorensr/ynm/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the custom _document.js and _app.js file as seen here in the example project https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs